# How to extract an object from NSString

Tags: objective-c, object, pointers, nsstring

It's quite easy get the class/address of an object as a string, using:

```
NSString* objectInfoString = [object description];
```

The string returned is something like `<ClassName: fk10009567>`, with the letters and numbers representing it's unique address in memory, as I understand it.

Or, for just the address, simply using a formatted NSString with the %p place holder.

```
NSString* addressString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%p",myObject];
```

Is it then possible to create a pointer from this string information?
For Example:

```
NSObject* foo = [[NSObject alloc]init];
NSString* fooAddressString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%p",foo];
```

Then, I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
NSObject* newFoo = [NSObject objectForAddressString:fooAddressString];
```

such that newFoo = foo is true.

Comment: Why? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: It's possible, but it's pointless. To get the description, you need the pointer. If you have the pointer, you already have the address. (Also, many classes print other things than the instance address for their description.)

Comment: Also the result of the `%p` format *could* be implementation dependent.

Comment: @JasperBlues - Printing the address and reading it back in is pointless and fragile/dangerous.

Comment: @JasperBlues - The OP has so far neglected to respond to the request that he explain *why* he wants to do this.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was using a mobile to check this question and didn't see all comments. @HotLicks I don't particularly want to do this, I just wanted to know if I can and in doing so understand objective c a little better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The foundation APIs provide a specific mechanism for doing this, without using 'magic strings', although you *could* do it using stringWithFormat, I guess. (It would be somewhat fragile, as noted).

***To get a pointer reference to the object:***

```
//Value now contains a pointer to the object, be careful it doesn't become dangling
NSValue* value = [NSValue valueWithPointer:(__bridge void*) myObject];
```

***To get the object back from the pointer reference:***

```
//If not using ARC you can skip the (__bridge id) here, and change the above cast to just (void*)
MyObjectType* myObject = (__bridge id) [value pointerValue];
```

**Fragility?**

It was noted that using '%p' to obtain a pointer value is fragile - while all Objective-C implementations currently return a hex value, the implementation of this *could* change. In any case, there's a specific API to do it.

Consider also that saving a reference to a pointer is fragile ***by nature*** in any case: Having obtained a pointer its necessary to ensure that it doesn't become 'dangling' - meaning the object being referenced goes away before the pointer does. The same strategies as using the __unsafe_unretained (aka assign) memory option should be applied. (No automatic weak references here!)

There are certainly valid applications of this kind of thing, however they are quite specialized and it would be unusual to find yourself doing this in everday apps programming. (I gathered you were asking the question simply to get a deeper understanding of Objective-C - kudos for that).

***What is a valid use of this technique?***

One valid application is to keep a reference to an Objective-C object in a C++ class. The [Box2d physics engine (C++)](http://box2d.org/) allows this to provide an integration point with various Objective-C sprite engines.

Comment: Thanks heaps :) Yes this was more about understanding than specific application

Answer (score 5):

This does not seem something sane or good thing to do. Relying on the `- description` of an object is very, **very** fragile. Why would you need to recover the object from its description? If you want to serialize and deserialize objects, you can do that by implementing the `NSCoding` protocol. If you want to associate objects with indices or keys, you can use `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`, etc...

That said, however, you **can** make a pointer out of a string:

```
NSString *addr = @"0xbadf00d";
uintptr_t ptr = strtoull(addr.UTF8String, NULL, 0);
id obj = (id)ptr;
```

Comment: I agree, relying on -description is very unsafe. Classes can implement -description however they like, there is no requirement to return a memory address as part of -description.

Comment: With ARC: `id obj = (__bridge id)(void *)ptr` :-)

Comment: @MartinR Yup :) I always forgot about that... I don't use ARC.

Comment: @H2CO3 You can do the same thing without ARC, just by dropping the __bridge casts.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. I understand that description is not particularly safe for retrieving the address in the first place (I have overriden it myself a few times). I'm am more interested in converting the already known string into an object :)